# Нужно найти элемент в классе. Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="col-xs-5 player-sidebar-value">261204</div>
```

Как я могу получить 261204?

Пробовал так

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[10]/div[2]')    
print(element)
```

Вывод:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6cb491f061aa7c1b6ae25df70ca65590", element="215546c2-3316-415d-a37a-bc8bc6090efb")>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement` есть свойство `text` им и нужно получать значение

Не советую пользоваться полными путями вида:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[10]/div[2]
```

Причины:

- Они страшные
- Они сильно зависят от верстки, т.к. описывается полный путь
- xpath менее читаемый, чем css-селекторы

Поэтому показываю решение через css-селектор:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.player-sidebar-value')    
print(element.text)
```

Тут будет поиск первого элемента, имеющего класс `player-sidebar-value`. Если таких элементов несколько понадобится добавить конкретики (по тегу, по родительским или дочерним элементам), но тут нужно смотреть "на месте"

Comment: Спасибо, всё понял , четко !